# How does "주간" translate to "daytime?"

Tags: vocabulary, hanja

I thought 주간 means "week" or "weekly" (literally "span of one week"), but if you add [an "에"](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ko&tl=en&text=%EC%A3%BC%EA%B0%84%EC%97%90&op=translate) or even [just "야간"](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ko&tl=en&text=%EC%A3%BC%EA%B0%84%2C%20%EC%95%BC%EA%B0%84&op=translate) for context, it becomes "daytime."

Can you explain this? Is it the same hanja used for "weekly?" There is a small chance it's just a problem with the automatic translations, but both Google translate and Papago give similar translations. And "day/night" makes more sense in the context where I originally found this.

Comment: Different hanjas are used. see; https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%A3%BC%EA%B0%84&range=all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

주간(週刊) means 'weekly'

주간(晝間) means 'daytime'

As you can see, they have completely different hanja and so have completely different meanings. This is very common in the korean language, and the meaning of most words are just dependant on context.